# move a class object through vectors

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

I am designing a port system that must be able to dock and undock a ship. The port has 3 docks, each having 10 rows containing 10 berths etc. I am using classes like this.

```
class ship
{
public:
    std::string name;
    std::string size;
private:
    void dock();
    void undock();
};

class berth
{
    std::vector<ship> ships;
    std::string size;
    bool inUse;
    ship _ship;
public:
    /*void dock();
    void undock();*/
};

class row
{   
    std::vector<berth> berths;
    bool full;
public: 

};

class dock
{
    std::vector<row> rows;
    bool full;
public: 
};

class port
{
    std::vector<dock> docks;
    bool full;
public:

};
```

What is the best way to move a ship object through the vectors to reach a berth so it can be docked there. New to using classes and vectors, any direction would be apreciated.

Comment: *What is the best way* - What have you tried?

Comment: you don't move the ship through the vectors - instead you navigate the hierarchy of objects to find the appropriate berth object, and then add the ship in there.

Comment: I have only tried placing an object inside a vector but then I don't know haw to move it through to the next vector after that. I haven't been able to find any examples at all so I'm trying to figure out how to go about it.

Comment: could you show me a small example of how you would go about doing that as I said im new to using classes.

Comment: you find the port you want, then within that port, you find the dock you want, then within that dock, you find the berth you want, and in that berth, you place the ship. The "finding" aspect will have to be whatever suits your needs, so we can't really help with that.

Comment: Its not the finding the berth that I am stuck with its the actual code to perform this that I don't know. To make it clear what would I need to move a ship object into a row. not to find the right row but just to move it into it.

Comment: please re-read my earlier comments - the ship never gets moved into a row - only into a berth.

Comment: okay so I need to store a ship object in each berth as the ships are entered into the system but I don't know how to store it in lets say for example the first birth, in the first row, in the first port. how would I go about doing that?

Comment: How would you go about doing that?

Comment: All your classes are missing a public function that would add a ship to it.

Comment: because the birth class is the only one that should actually store a ship. Is that wrong because the row doesn't hold a ship it holds berths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple realization of docking could be done by changing your code slightly:

```
class ship
{
public:
    ship(std::string name_) : name(name_) { }
    std::string name;
};

class berth
{
public:
    berth() : ships(10, 0) { }
    std::vector<ship *> ships;
};

class row
{   
public:
    row() : berths(10) { }
    std::vector<berth> berths;
};

class dock
{
public:
    dock() : rows(10) { }
    std::vector<row> rows;
};

class port
{
public:
    port() : docks(3) { }
    void Dock(ship * ship_, int dockId, int rowId, int berthId, int shipId)
    {
        docks[dockId].rows[rowId].berths[berthId].ships[shipId] = ship_;
    }
    void Undock(int dockId, int rowId, int berthId, int shipId)
    {
        docks[dockId].rows[rowId].berths[berthId].ships[shipId] = 0;
    }

    std::vector<dock> docks;
};

int main()
{
    port port_;

    ship titanic("Titanic");

    port_.Dock(&titanic, 0, 0, 4, 2); 

    return 0;
}
```

First of all, you need some way to initialize all sizes of your port. It could be done using constructors. For example, `berth() : port() : docks(3) { }` initializes port with 3 docks (resizes `vector<dock> docks` to hold `docks[0]`, `docks[1]` and `docks[2]` elements which are your docks in port). Next you need some information about is there a ship docked at exact place in berth. It could be done in several ways, however, I changed ships vector to hold pointers to ships. So if there is no ship in `berth[i]` there will be 0, otherwise there will be pointer to the ship. So to initialize berth correctly its constructor looks like `berth() : ships(10, 0) {}`. It means that berth has 10 places to put ships, and 0 pointer at any of them. Now the last step is to make Dock/Undock methods to manipulate ships in port. You can access them via vector indexes.
It's rather simple. However it's C++ and there are some sharks in the water of port. When creating you program you should decide who is the owner of ship. Logically port is not the owner, it can't make or destroy ship, it just can provide information about what ships are docked in it at what berths. So I've decided to hold pointers to ships at berths and hold ships themselves somewhere else. In this case you need to use port and ships with precautions. If you destroy a ship witch is docked and don't update information about it in port, it will lead to disasters in your program. For example, we can modify the code in main is such a way:

```
int main()
{
    port port_;

    {
        //titanic is constructed
        ship titanic("Titanic");

        port_.Dock(&titanic, 0, 0, 4, 2);

    }//titinic has drown (destructured)

    ship * docked_ship = port_.docks[0].rows[0].berths[4].ships[2];
    if(docked_ship != 0) //points to already destroyed object!
        cout << "Ship with name : " << docked_ship->name << " is docked in the port"; //program crash

    return 0;
}
```

and things become really bad. So watch out and think about lifetimes of objects and pointers to them.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there's a 1-to-1 relationship between a berth and a ship, although I see you have a vector  inside a berth which I don't quite understand. Also I assume a ship doesn't care what berth it's assigned.

What you could do is create a producer - consumer scenario in which every Berth is a unit of resource "produced" by your port and each Ship "consumes" one unit of resource. Make each Berth know to which (dock, row, position) it corresponds i.e add some internal data.

You can make one Queue with available Berths -

```
std::queue<Berth> free_berths;
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/

-------> For every incoming Ship you free_berths.pop() a Berth from the queue and you dock() onto it. If the queue is empty that means there's no more available slots you can deal with this case as you see fit.

<------- For every Ship that undocks() you free_berths.push() the released Berth back into the queue.

In this way you separate the logic from any detail regarding how many docks, rows, berths there are of even if they are organised in the same manner.

## ===============

This framework can easily be  extended to more complicated use case scenarios:

1) Make produce - consume relationship multi-threaded by wrapping with synchronized code that part that deals with modifying the queue. Moreover, you can add a separate Queue for Ships:

```
std::queue<Ship> incoming_ships;
```

that multiple threads can write to and a middleware thread that constantly tries to pop() and match entries from both free_berths and incoming_ships.

2) If you want to prioritize using Berths from certain docks/rows you can use

```
std::priority_queue<Berth, "some_comparator"> free_berths;
```

instead by creating a Comparator based on dock/rows numbers and the job is done by design.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/priority_queue/

Comment: That does seem like a good approach to take but there are three types of birth small, medium, large. a small boat can fit in all 3 medium in the larger two etc. would you make three queue one for each sized ship or would I be better off having three separate berths?

Comment: I should have made my question much clearer, apologies

Comment: A straight-forward approach would be indeed to have the 3 separate berth  queues and modify the dock() method of the port to try to pop from them in order: 
` void dock(Ship & new_ship) {
switch (new_ship.size):
case SMALL:
}
`

Comment: A straight-forward approach would be indeed to have the 3 separate berth  queues and modify the dock() method of the port to try to pop from them in order: 
`void dock(Ship & new_ship) {
switch (new_ship.size):
case SMALL:
 if (!free_small_berths.empty()) {
  new_ship.dock(free_small_berths.pop());
  break;
  }
case MEDIUM:
 if (!free_medium_berths.empty()) {
  new_ship.dock(free_medium_berths.pop());
  break;
  }
... same for LARGE
}`
'break' is used only if a berth is found because in this way for a medium boat for example it will first search in medium, then in large queue

Comment: I think if i had more time i would use this method but i don't know enough about queues and such. thanks for the help!